# What my code needs a gen.sleep to execute a function async?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado, python-asyncio, tornado-redis

I have the following code written based on Python's Tornado:

```
def process_data(data):
    # To something

def handler(message):
    if message['type'] == 'message':
        data = message['data']
        IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(process_data, data)

async def main():
    redis_client = RedisClient(redis_conf)
    pubsub = redis_client.subscribe("CHANNEL", handler)

    async def fetch_messages():
        while True:
            pubsub.get_message()
            await gen.sleep(0.0001) 


    await fetch_messages()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import logging
    logging.basicConfig()

    parse_command_line()

    tornado.web.Application(debug=options.debug)

    io_loop = ioloop.IOLoop.current()
    io_loop.run_sync(main)
```

Given the above code I can see that `process_data` is being called. However, if I remove await `gen.sleep(0.0001)`, `process_data` is never called. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> IOLoop.spawn_callback(callback, *args, **kwargs)
>
> Calls the given callback **on the next IOLoop iteration**.

If you're keep calling some synchronous code (`while True` without `await`) you don't return control to event loop and event loop can't make it's iteration to execute callback.

Line `await gen.sleep(0.0001)` - is where controls returns to event loop so it can do something (like executing callbacks).

Tornado has special object to return control to event loop for such cases as yours - [gen.moment](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.moment):

```
    while True:
        pubsub.get_message()
        await gen.moment
```

I didn't work with Tornado, but I bet that even better would be to use some redis client designed to be used in async programs, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15161744/1113207).